# Is it possible to write a packet, read by libpcap, with libnet? in c?

Tags: c, libpcap, packet-capture, libnet, packet-injection

I'm trying to get libpcap to read a pcap file, get the user to select a packet and write that packet using libnet, in c.

I got the reading from file part done. Libpcap puts that packet into a const unsigned char. I have worked with libnet before, but never with libnet's advanced functions. I would just create the packet using libnet's build functions, then let them on their way. I realize there is a function, `libnet_adv_write_link()` that takes the libnet context, a pointer to a packet to inject(const uint8_t) and the size of the packet. I tried passing the 'packet' that I got from libpcap, and it compiled and executed without errors. However, I am not seeing anything in wireshark.

Would this be the right way to tackle this problem, or should I read from libpcap and build a separate packet with libnet, based on what libpcap read?

EDIT: I believe I somewhat solved the problem. I read the packet with libpcap. Put all the bytes after the 16th byte into another uchar and wrote that into the wire. using libnet_adv_write_raw_ipv4(), libnet initialized with LIBNET_RAW4_ADV. I believe, maybe because of the driver, I don't have much power over the ETH layer. so basically I just let it be written automatically this way, and the new uchar packet is just whatever is left after the ETH layer in the original packet. Works fine so far.

Comment: Just making sure, libnet_adv_write_link()'s returned value is ok (not -1)?

Comment: @Arnon Zilca - It returns the number of bytes it wrote. I think thats normal. Nothing is written though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the current libnet maintainer.

You should call libnet_write_link() to write a packet. If you aren't seeing it, its possible you haven't opened the correct device, that you lack permissions (you checked the return value of libnet_write_link I hope), and also possible that the packet injected was invalid.

If you don't need to build the packet, it sounds like you should be using pcap to send the packet, though, see http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_inject.3pcap.html

Also, your statement "Libpcap puts that packet into a const unsigned char" is odd. A packet doesn't fit in a single char, what pcap does is, depending on the API, return pointers into the packet data. Its worth including a snippet of code showing how you get the packet from data, and how you pass it to libnet. Its possible you aren't using the pointers correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what i shouldve said was const unsigned char array. I can print out the bytes of the packet with a loop and compare with what i see in wireshark. Also I think I managed to get that packet written to the wire somehow, after some tweaking. But then I encountered another problem: some of the bytes of the packet get written differently. Like the protocol in the eth layer becomes Ethernet(0x0003) whereas it should have been IP(0x0080). Do you think this is caused by some other application that interferes with packets? I'm using Ubuntu Linux. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried sending the packet with libnet_adv_write_link(), libnet_write_link(), pcap_inject(), pcap_sendpacket(). [http://i.imgur.com/fBreQnX.png] What, do you think, would be the solution? How can I just send only what I have in that char array? (also the 00s on the bottom of my sent packet are there because I'd passed 100 as the size to those functions)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using `libpcap`, why not use `libpcap` to send the packet? No, it's not well known, but yes it does work. See the function `pcap_sendpacket`.
2. The packet `libpcap` returns is simply an array of bytes. Anything that takes an array of bytes (including the ethernet frame) should work. However, note that your OS and/or hardware may stop you from sending packets with incorrect or malformed source MAC addresses.